# Вызов функции Python с *args или по умолчанию

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, исключения

Имеется некий код (рабочий для Python 3.8.10):

```
 def select (table, *columns):
       try:
           conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname='db', user='u', password='p', host='localhost')
           cursor = conn.cursor(cursor_factory=psycopg2.extras.NamedTupleCursor)
       except Exception as e:
           print (e.__doc__)
           if hasattr(e, 'message'): print (e.message)
      else:
          cursor.execute('SELECT '+','.join(map(str,columns))+ ' FROM ' + table)
          for row in cursor:
              print(row)
      finally:
          if 'cursor' in locals(): cursor.close()
          if ('conn' in locals() and conn): conn.close()
 
  #select('table_name','id','price','sku','date')
  #select('table_name') - не работает(
  #select('table_name','*') - атрибуты не найдены
```

Как задать значение по умолчанию "*" (задействовать в SQL запросе все столбцы), так чтобы при отсутствии *columns оно было использовано, а при наличии хотя бы одного *columns исчезло?
Все мои попытки тщетны и возвращают синтаксические ошибки.

Comment: "атрибуты не найдены" - подробнее ошибку напишите, а то выглядит вполне норм.

Comment: @eri так и есть Attribute not found.
Больше ничего(

Comment: Не, там ещё список строк которые вызывались до ошибки

Answer (score 2):

```
      columns_q = ','.join(map(str,columns)) or "*"
      cursor.execute('SELECT '+columns_q+ ' FROM ' + table)
```

Comment: Attribute not found.